# How to avoid Error: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

Tags: c#, .net

I have a legacy app which will write to the event log if the proper source exists.  When I run with an insufficiently privileged account, I get this error:

```
The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
```

The code exectuing is:

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists("foo"))
```

Now I really do not care if it exists or not, and would like to test if the account has access.  Is there a good way to do this without simply catching that exception?